# take screenshots programmatically in bge?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, camera

```
import bge

from bge import render, logic

def makescreenshot():
    path = logic.expandPath("//")

    def main(): 

        cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
        own = cont.owner

        render.makeScreenshot(path+"image.png")

    main()
makescreenshot()
```

^This is the code I have to take a screenshot of the current scene and I want to connect this with an always sensor to the camera, but the only way I know to do so is by using bpy...is there any way to take screenshots using bpy or is there any way to add logic bricks using bge?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to create logic bricks setup in Blender? I think that is possible. I can remember someone published a generator to be used by the node editor. Btw. makeScreenshot() supports "//" already and the code does not benefit from the nested function "main". So you can get really simple code. - edit: I just checked he generated the python code not the bricks. - sorry

Comment: The Blender API http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_3/bpy.ops.logic.html contains something like this: bpy.ops.logic.controller_add(). It might help you to investigate further.

Answer (score -1):

In Bge you can indeed add an always sensor and link it to the python script

[image]